# detect locked file

Tags: java

Given a reference to a `File` instance, is it possible to (programatically) detect whether the corresponding file is locked, and if so, which process is holding the lock?

I'm using Java 5, running on Windows.

Thanks,
Don

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500174/checking-if-a-file-locked-in-java

Comment: Does this thread help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390592/java-check-if-file-is-already-open

Comment: I'm using Sysinternal's Procexp app for this detection which is famous for using low level and undocumented Windows apis, so I would never expect it to be possible in Java. But if there is a way, it would be great.

Comment: @calavera perhaps there is a way to wrap this in a java process. Does it have a Command Line interface?

Comment: @seanizer I don't think that there is a command line interface and besides the christian's solution is the right way to use native os features.

Comment: If you're willing to write c++ code, yes. But the question was about java.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is only possible in a native way. You need to access FileHandle informations. Write a Dll and connect it to your java app via JNI. Call NtQuerySystemInformation with SystemHandleInformation(16). You get a list with all open Handles, search for FileHandles, compare FileHandles with your own File.