# Reading Excel file safely using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI and whenever I am going to save it and if it is open using Microsoft Excel Viewer then It is not being saved and it is also giving any error or exception. Is there any way to determine this?

Comment: That's caused by Excel locking the file. What do you mean by "any way to determine this"? Just catch the exception and do whatever you want. See also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500174/checking-if-a-file-locked-in-java

Comment: You should provide more information. For example the Exception is needed here to see the source of your problem. Also the code, that throw it,  is necessary to help you.