# File Name Not Able to Change

Tags: java

I am looking for a way to convert my old file to a new file after my program processes the file. The new file should contain the current timestamp after it's been processed. For example, my old file is `test.txt`. After it's been processed, it should change to `test2017-10-13.txt`. I have searched for the solution around internet, but I still can't make it work. Here is my current source code

```
LocalDate now2 = LocalDate.now(); 
System.out.println("The current day is :" +now2);
File oldFile1 = new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\test.txt");
File newFile1 = new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\test"+now2+".txt");
boolean success = oldFile1.renameTo(newFile1);
System.out.println(success);
```

This is my sample output

```
The current day is :2017-10-13
false
```

Is it a known bug with java? I found this [information](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6213298) online. Is there any method to do it without copying out the contents from the older file and writing it into the new file ?

Comment: Are you sure the "test.txt" file is existed?

Comment: yes,it's existed, because the IOException didn't raised

Comment: no, you should call `file.exists()` to see. If it is not existed, the `rename` will return false

Comment: `renameTo` doesn't generate a `IOException`, it just returns `true`/`false` depending on the success of the operation

Comment: yes, my file is existed after I add it the file.exists()

Comment: Did you have test.txt opened? (The program still running, not calling `close`.)

Answer (score 0):

One common reason it return false is because your file is locked that's why it return false. Check if you open it in any application OR if your application itself locking it somewhere.

You can check [Check if a file is locked in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500174/check-if-a-file-is-locked-in-java)

Comment: this is very possible reason. use file.setReadable() And file.setWritable while creating files.

Comment: note: writable in window is only changing the "Read Only" flag so it won't affect the file renaming.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        File file = new File("D:\\test\\test1.txt");
        File newFile = new File("D:\\test\\test"+dateFormat.format(cal.getTime())+".txt");
        if(file.renameTo(newFile)){
            System.out.println("File rename success");;
        }else{
            System.out.println("File rename failed");
        }
```

Comment: do it applicable for csv file as well ?

Comment: Yes it should, but you need to make changes in above code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is, to check the file exists or not first. Then, perform IO operation.

```
    if (oldFile1.exists()) {
        boolean success = oldFile1.renameTo(newFile1);
        System.out.println(success);
    }
    else
    {
         System.out.println("failed");
    }
```

I'm assuming, the path, which you were using there `user` is just place holder and when you are running below code then you are changing it to your actual `user` name.

```
C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\test
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your file readable/writable. Sometime your file has read only access.

Second thing, You Should close streams (if used).

Try this:

```
               File f;
               f=new File("zzzz.txt");
               LocalDate ld=LocalDate.now();

               f.renameTo(new File("Hello "+ld.toString()+".txt"));
               System.out.println(f.getAbsoluteFile()+"  "+f.exists());
```

Out put is:
Hello 2017-10-12.txt

Comment: a file zzzz.txt exist and to rename this I used a temp file here.

Comment: Applicable for any kind of file including csv files.